# Using Scanner to read all files in folder one at a time gives NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, file-handling, nosuchelementexception

Following Java code:

```
File folder = new File("/home");
File[] listofFiles = folder.listFiles();
for (j = 0; j < listofFiles.length; j++) {
  File file = listofFiles[j];
  if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".ucf")) {
      String content = new Scanner(new File(file.getName())).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
      for(i=0;i<content.length-10;i++)
      // do something..
      content = null;
  } // close if..
}
```

throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
     at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
     at c.main(c.java:18)
```

However, earlier when I was using Scanner to read a particular file to String `content`, there was no such error at `Scanner.next()`. Now it gives this exception when I try to traverse through all files.

Comment: where exactly do you get the exception, when using the debugger?

Comment: You need to check if content is present or not before reading it using `hasNextInt()` method.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav as you said, an empty file was giving the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoSuchElementException` occurs when no more tokens are available.

try this when you are reading

```
 if(scanner.hasNext())
 scanner.next();
```

Comment: Damn it, an empty file was giving the exception and your answer is correct. Thanks